# Can't download a file in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

Here is my code to download a book

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

    NSString *filePath= [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:_bookname];//in _bookname i am already  getting the value ,say abcd.pdf

    NSLog(@"The bookfilepath is %@",filePath);

    NSLog(@"the lenght of recieved data is %d", _recievedData.length);//here i get the correct file size also 

    [_recievedData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    NSFileManager *filemgr;

    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: filePath] == YES)
    {
        flag=1;
        NSLog (@"File exists");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog (@"File not found");  //always this happens in the log
    }
}
```

No file exists at the `filePath`. Why?
The funny part is `_recievedData.length` is returning the correct file size.

Comment: Never never never write `if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: filePath] == YES)`. A "true" condition can yield many values other than YES. `fileExistsAtPath:` is _already_ a boolean. Write `if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: filePath])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you cannot write into the app bundle (`[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]`).

Write to the documents folder instead.

Comment: Look at the code. The OP is trying to write to the Documents folder. The problem is that the code in the question worked in the past (even though it was never the proper way to access the Documents folder) but it doesn't work any more with newer iOS versions.

Comment: @rmaddy No that doesn't write to the Documents folder.

Comment: Oops - I take that back. The use of `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent` actually would give the wrong path.

Comment: Anyway, my point is that the OP's code indicates that they thought they were trying to write to the Documents folder. They are just doing it incorrectly. So your answer doesn't really help them much. It would be better, like Rob's answer, to show them the proper way instead of just telling them to do what they already think they are doing.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that this code getting the resource path, stripping off the last path component and then adding `Documents`. That's not the right way to get to the Documents folder. Instead, use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`:

```
NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *filePath      = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:_bookname];
```

Comment: On iOS, you should also study the documentation to find which directory should be used. There is NSDocumentDirectory, NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSCachesDirectory, and NSTemporaryDirectory(), all with different purposes.

Comment: I agree. He should refer to [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) and confirm whether Documents is the correct folder or not. I inferred from his code sample that he was trying to get to Documents, so I just wanted to illustrate the correct way to do that.